# How can I extract JSON values using for-comprehensions

Tags: scala, lift-json

I want to extract JSON values usgin for-comprehensions

my code is this:

```
import net.liftweb.json._

val json = parse("""     
{
    "took": 212,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 0.625,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "siteindex",
                "_type": "posts",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.625,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title 1",
                    "content": "content 1"
                },
                "highlight": {
                    "title": [
                        "<b>title</b> 1"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "siteindex",
                "_type": "posts",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.19178301,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title 4",
                    "content": "content 4"
                },
                "highlight": {
                    "title": [
                        "<b>title</b> 4"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "siteindex",
                "_type": "posts",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.19178301,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title 2",
                    "content": "content 2"
                },
                "highlight": {
                    "title": [
                        "<b>title</b> 2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "siteindex",
                "_type": "posts",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.19178301,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title 3",
                    "content": "content 3"
                },
                "highlight": {
                    "title": [
                        "<b>title</b> 3"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}      
""")
```

my "case class" is this:

```
case class Document(title:String, content:String)
```

my "for" is this:

```
val ret: List[Document] = for {
  JObject(child)                          <- json
  JField("title",       JString(title))   <- child
  JField("content",     JString(content)) <- child
} yield (Document( title, content  ))
```

and my "list" is this:

```
ret: List[Document] = List(Document(title 1,content 1), Document(title 4,content 4), Document(title 2,content 2), Document(title 3,content 3))
```

until here everything is fine!

but now i need something like this:

```
List(Document2(1,<b>title</b> 1,content 1), Document2(4,<b>title</b> 4,content 4), Document2(2,<b>title</b> 2,content 2), Document2(3,<b>title</b> 3,content 3))
```

i need the value of:

```
 "highlight": {
                    "title": [
                        "<b>*</b> *"
                    ]
                }
```

and this:

```
"_id": "*",
```

in my list.

my "case class" is this:

```
case class Document2(_id:String, title:String, content:String)
```

i try this, but it does not work

```
val ret: List[Document2] = for {
  JObject(child)                          <- json
  JField("_id",         JString(_id))     <- child
  JField("title",       JString(title))   <- child
  JField("content",     JString(content)) <- child
} yield (Document2( _id, title, content  ))
```

i don't know, if there is a better way of data extraction for this json

but the result is this:

```
<console>:23: warning: `withFilter' method does not yet exist on net.liftweb.json.JValue, using `filter' method instead
         JObject(child)                          <- json

ret: List[Document2] = List()
```

any suggestion please
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer similar to the approach from @flav, but I'll give you the structure to map to the json and how to get your end result too.  First, the case classes:

```
case class Document2(_id:String, title:String, content:String)

case class Results(hits:HitsList)
case class HitsList(hits:List[Hit])
case class Hit(_id:String, _source:Source, highlight:Highlight)
case class Source(title:String, content:String)
case class Highlight(title:List[String])
```

Then, the code for parsing it and converting it:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val results = json.extract[Results]
val docs2 = results.hits.hits.map{ hit => 
  Document2(hit._id, hit.highlight.title.head, hit._source.content)
}
```